# Using JavaScript modules on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

How can I configure Heroku to have the flag `--experimental-modules` supplied to the Node.js executable to ensure I can use native modules in my JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem and solved it by adding a start script in the `package.json` file of my application as below:

```
"scripts": {
    …

    "start": "node --experimental-modules index.mjs ",

    …
}
```

For more details, see the topic "Specifying a start script" in [Specifying a start script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script).